# Select an object from a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a basic class where I define some attributes.

```
public class Cliente
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public bool Enviado { get; set; }

    public Cliente(string id, string nome, string cpf, string email, string baseDados = "TV", bool enviado = false)
    {
        ID = id;
        Nome = nome;
        CPF = cpf;
        Email = email;
        Enviado = enviado;
        Base = baseDados;
    }
}
```

My List

```
List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>();
```

How can I select an item in this list having access to the attributes of the class?

```
Cliente c = clientes.Select(x => x.Enviado == false);
```

I've tried it that way, but Select returns a bool right? I tried using Where as well, but it does not return the object

Comment: If you only want one, you need [`First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx), [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Single()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx), [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx), etc.  [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, `T` being the type that you selected in the lambda.  So in your case you are returning an `IEnumerable<bool>`

Comment: `Where` will return an `IEnumerable<Cliente>` of all the objects in the list that match.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FirstOrDefault` like this:

```
Cliente c = clientes.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.Enviado);
```

Comment: Thank you, friend, it worked perfectly now.

Comment: @KrolNoir no probs. Also, it would be wise to read maccettura's comment under your post as it's spot on :) .

Answer (score 0):

```
Cliente c = clientes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Enviado == false);
```

Comment: The `Where` is completely unnecessary here, put the lambda in `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @maccettura yes i am aware...but teaches the basics to new people